# Function EXTRACT() does not return the correct result

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the years users with this query using the function EXTRACT:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM contact.BIRTHDATE) AS CONTACT_YEARS 
FROM CONTACT contact
```

but for some dates, **for example**: contact.BIRTHDATE = '27-AGO-40' the function EXTRACT(YEAR FROM contact.BIRTHDATE) return 2040 and query does not work.

I also tried using `to_date(contact.BIRTHDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy')` 
but the date format does not change.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you *sure* that birthdate is set to 1940 (assuming this is the problem)? I seem to recall Oracle have a pivot at 1950 so that two digit dates will be assumed to be 1950 thru 2049 inclusive.

Comment: Try `select to_char(contact.BIRTHDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy')` and check the result. This will probaly tell you that you have issues in your data. Also, notice that applying `to_date' to a date column does not make sense.

Comment: I also tried buit the results is:
-32 27/08/2049
53 26/01/1964
33 17/07/1983
36 26/10/1980
62 18/10/1954 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only displaying the year component of the date with two-digits. If you display the full year then you will likely see that the dates have the incorrect century.

Also, rather than subtracting the years to get the difference in years, you would be better using:

```
TRUNC( MONTHS_BETWEEN( sysdate, birthdate ) / 12 )
```

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE contact( BIRTHDATE DATE );

INSERT INTO contact ( birthdate )
SELECT DATE '1977-03-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '77-03-29'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '1977-03-30' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( birthdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) AS full_year,
       TO_CHAR( birthdate, 'YY-MM-DD' )   AS short_year,
       EXTRACT( YEAR FROM sysdate ) - EXTRACT( YEAR FROM birthdate ) AS age,
       TRUNC( MONTHS_BETWEEN( sysdate, birthdate ) / 12 ) AS actual_age
FROM   contact;
```

**Output**:

```
FULL_YEAR  SHORT_YEAR AGE  ACTUAL_AGE
---------- ---------- ---- ----------
1977-03-29 77-03-29     40         40
0077-03-29 77-03-29   1940       1940
1977-03-30 77-03-30     40         39
```