# "Not a valid month" or number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Getting this error while trying to put a few inserts into a table.

Getting an error regarding not a valid month and when I try change it around i'm getting invalid number error.

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL"
```

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE ExpenseReport (
    ERNo            NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL, 
    ERDesc          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    ERSubmitDate    DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    ERStatusDate    DATE NOT NULL, 
    ERStatus        VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT 'PENDING', 
    SubmitUserNo    NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL, 
    ApprUserNo      NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT ExpenseReport_CK1 CHECK (ERStatusDate >= ERSubmitDate), 
    CONSTRAINT ExpenseReport_CK2 CHECK (ERStatus = 'PENDING'/'APPROVED'/'DENIED'), 
    CONSTRAINT ExpenseReport_PK1 PRIMARY KEY(ERNo), 
    CONSTRAINT ExpenseReport_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(SubmitUserNo) REFERENCES Users(UserNo), 
    CONSTRAINT ExpenseReport_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(ApprUserNo) REFERENCES (USerNo)
); 

INSERT INTO ExpenseReport 
    (ERNo, ERDesc, ERSubmitDate, ERStatusDate, ERStatus, SubmitUserNo, ApprUSerNo)
    VALUES (1,'Sales Presentation','8/10/2002','8/26/2002','APPROVED',3,4);
```

I've also tried using the `TO_DATE` but having no luck there,
by any chance can anyone see where i'm going wrong.

Comment: are you saying, `to_date('8/26/2002' , 'mm/dd/yyyy')` doesn't work ?

Comment: Ive also tried doing it this way                                                      
INSERT INTO ExpenseReport 
 (ERNo, ERDesc, ERSubmitDate, ERStatusDate, ERStatus, SubmitUserNo, ApprUSerNo)
 VALUES (1,'Sales Presentation',TO_DATE('01/01/02','DD/MM/YY'),TO_DATE('02/02/03','DD/MM/YY'),'APPROVED',3,4);

Comment: @John - and what happened when you did that? (Also, why are you using 2-digit years in this one? You seem to have switch day and month around too?)

Comment: @AlexPoole - Just trying anything to try get it to work, ive tried both the 2-digit for years and 4-digits based on from what ive seen on other questions. I keep getting a error regarding the month number for some reason

Comment: The code you showed in that comment won't throw that error though. You usually get that if you've confused days and months, often implicitly, as in your original statement in the question.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`DATE` keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) and standard date formats:

```
INSERT INTO ExpenseReport (ERNo, ERDesc, ERSubmitDate, ERStatusDate, ERStatus, SubmitUserNo, ApprUSerNo)
    VALUES (1, 'Sales Presentation', DATE '2001-08-10', DATE '2001-08-2006', 'APPROVED', 3, 4);
```

In addition to the satisfaction of using standard date formats, this protects you against changes in local settings.

Comment: tried using that bit of code there and i am still getting this error  ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Comment: @John - invalid number is nothing to do with the date conversion, that's coming from another column. In fact, from your check constraint ExpenseReport_CK2. Look at that more closely...

Comment: @AlexPoole - I've a similar column as this without the date and it's working perfectly. I think the date is throwing everything out in this, is it possible that different formats for time and date will affect this as I am using the european format?

Comment: @John - no, you're seeing two unrelated issues. You only see the number problem from the constraint once you've fixed the date issue that it is hitting first.

Answer (score 5):

In your DDL statement:

```
CONSTRAINT ExpenseReport_CK2 CHECK (ERStatus = 'PENDING'/'APPROVED'/'DENIED')
```

Should be:

```
CONSTRAINT ExpenseReport_CK2 CHECK (ERStatus IN ( 'PENDING', 'APPROVED', 'DENIED' ) )
```

When you are trying to insert values the check constraint is being evaluated and it is trying to perform a division operation on the three string values`'PENDING'/'APPROVED'/'DENIED'` which results in `ORA-01722: invalid number`.

Once you change this then using `TO_DATE('01/01/02','DD/MM/YY')` (as you wrote in comments) or an ANSI date literal `DATE '2002-01-01'` should work in your DML statements.

*(Note: Be careful using 2-digit years or you can find that [dates are inserted with the wrong century.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43090440/1509264))*

Answer (score 1):

```
Check your date format: select sysdate from dual;
```

and enter as it show. OR

```
change your date format: alter session set nls_date_format= 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the NLS settings, or use implicit conversions. Except for one-off, ad hoc code, always explicitly state the format - either with `to_date()` and a suitable mask, or preferably - as Gordon already said - with date literals. Your code could be run in a client or session you don't control, so don't give it an opportunity to break over something trivial.

Answer (score -1):

It Was Easy :
if Your code Like This just remove hem and write that

Example :
Your code : values ('30178','K111', '22/12/2008')
Do This : values ('30178','K111', '22/Dec/2008')